# Compile a directive with templateUrl into string and wait for delayed link function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-compile

I want to `$compile` a piece of html that contains several directives into a string and send this to the server. Since some directives contain a `templateUrl`, the returned link function is delayed. In this question ([AngularJS: Using $compile on html that contains directives with templateurl](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27008280/498298)) the problem seems to be solved calling `$scope.$digest()` which is not possible in my case (already in progress).

The only solution I've found, is to use a timeout, see http://plnkr.co/edit/k3ZAYy1FhGUFXxXyrPvB?p=preview

Is there a better way to wait for the completion of the delayed link function?

Answer (score 0):

in your runURL function, use a $apply like:

```
this.runUrl = function() {
    var scope = $rootScope.$new();
    var html = '<template-url-directive></template-url-directive>';
    var compiled = $compile(html);
    var el = compiled(scope);
    scope.$apply();
    this.result = el[0].outerHTML;
  };
```

That works to bind the scope with the template. Please check the edited [plunk.](http://plnkr.co/edit/0LKRQc0FSuDO3OfrXdJH?p=preview)

Comment: I get `Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress`. I think it works only because the error in `apply()` needs enough time to load the template.